# Groovy - readYaml() expecting java.util.LinkedHashMap instead of a file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

As a part of our Jenkins solutions, we use Groovy in our pipelines.
In one of our groovy file I want to update a docker-stack.yaml.

To do so I'm using readYaml():

```
stage("Write docker-stack.yaml") {
        def dockerStackYamlToWrite = readFile 'docker-stack.yaml'

        def dockerStackYaml = readYaml file: "docker-stack.yaml"
        def imageOrigin = dockerStackYaml.services[domain].image
        def versionSource = imageOrigin.substring(imageOrigin.lastIndexOf(":") + 1, imageOrigin.length())
        def imageWithNewVersion = imageOrigin.replace(versionSource, imageTag)

        dockerStackYamlToWrite = dockerStackYamlToWrite.replace(imageOrigin, imageWithNewVersion)

        sh "rm docker-stack.yaml"
        writeFile file: "docker-stack.yaml", text: dockerStackYamlToWrite
        sh "git add docker-stack.yaml"
        sh "git commit -m 'promote dockerStack to ${envname}'"
        sh "git push origin ${envname}"
}
```

I am using test to validate my code:

```
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test

class TestUpdateVersionInDockerStack extends JenkinsfileBaseTest {

    @Before
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        helper.registerAllowedMethod("build", [Map.class], null)
        helper.registerAllowedMethod("steps", [Object.class], null)

        super.setUp()
    }

    @Test void success() throws Exception {
        def script = loadScript("src/test/jenkins/updateVersionInDockerStack/success.jenkins")
        script.execute()
    }
}
```

Here is the success.jenkins:

```
def execute() {
    node() {
        stage("Build") {
            def version = buildVersion()
            updateVersionInDockerStack([
                DOMAIN      : "security-package",
                IMAGE_TAG   : version,
                GITHUB_ORGA : "Bla",
                TARGET_ENV  : "int"
            ])
        }
    }
}

return this
```

When I run my test I get this message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: updateVersionInDockerStack.readYaml() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[file:docker-stack.yaml]]
```

At this point I'm lost. For what I understand from the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) readYaml() can I a file as an argument.

Can you help to understand why it is expecting a LinkedHashMap? Do you have to convert my value in a LinkedHashMap?

Thank you

Comment: actually when you calling `readYaml file: "docker-stack.yaml"` - you calling `readYaml` with map `[ file: "docker-stack.yaml" ]` as a parameter. and error says that there is no such method. possible you version of jenkins pipeline does not have this method yet...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't think it is because of the Jenkins pipeline version. This groovy file was already used and worked well. My job is to add a test for another groovy file calling updateVersionInDockerStack. But I saw there was no test for this one, so I decided to create a test for it too. So looks like the guy before (not anymore in the company) didn't bother with proper testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipeline unit test fails, because there is no `readYaml` method registered in pipeline's allowed methods. In your `TestUpdateVersionInDockerStack` test class simply add to the `setUp` method following line:

```
helper.registerAllowedMethod("readYaml", [Map.class], null)
```

This will instruct Jenkins pipeline unit environment that the method `readYaml` that accepts a single argument of type `Map` is allowed to use in the pipeline and invocation of this method will be registered in the unit test result stack. You can add a method `printCallStack()` call to your test method to see the stack of all executed steps during the test:

```
@Test void success() throws Exception {
    def script = loadScript("src/test/jenkins/updateVersionInDockerStack/success.jenkins")
    script.execute()
    printCallStack()
}
```

Comment: It seems to be the solution! Thank you. I've got new errors but I have to look a bit to solve it.

Comment: do you have any documentation to learn more about `registerAllowedMethod` (except the GitHub [page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit))? The first argument is the name of the method to test, the second is the arguments of the method. But the last know here _null_? Thank you